# basics of tensor calculus - covariant basis

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, covariance

I am reading a "Primer on Tensor Calculus" by Clark from [here](https://www.ap.smu.ca/%7Edclarke/home/documents/byDAC/tprimer.pdf).

In Def. 3.5 he defines a covariant basis vector as:
Let $\vec{r}_x$ be a displacement vector whose components are expressed in terms of the coordinate system $x^i$. Then the covariant basis vector $\vec{e}_i$ is defined to be:

$$
\begin{align}
\vec{e}_i \equiv \frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{r}_x}{\mathrm{d}x^i}
\end{align}
$$

Then he invokes that because the differential displacement vector is:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}\vec{r} = \sum_{i} h_{(i)}\mathrm{d}x^i\hat{e}_{(i)}
\end{align}
$$
where $\hat{e}_{(i)}$ are unit "physical" vectors, it follows that:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{e}_i = h_{(i)}\hat{e}_{(i)}
\end{align}
$$

I don't understand what he means by the symbol $\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{r}_x}{\mathrm{d}x^i}$. From what i remember, this should be a tangent to the $x^i$ coordinate line, but if that is so, I would write it as $\frac{\partial\vec{r}_x}{\partial x^i}$. The way he writes it it looks like some division but then I am not sure how to show the covariant character of this vector.

Secondly, how does he get $\mathbb{e}_i = h_{(i)}\hat{e}_{(i)}$ just using the definition and the differential displacement?

Comment: I think this is easier to understand using a simple example. In polar coordinates $(x^1=r,\, x^2=\theta)$ we have $\vec{r}_x=r\hat{r}$. Now the difference is $\frac{\partial \vec{r}_x}{\partial \theta}=0$ while $\frac{d \vec{r}_x}{d \theta}=\frac{dr}{d\theta}\hat{r}+r\frac{d \hat{r}}{d \theta}=r\hat{\theta}$. If you want to only use the partial derivatives you need to keep in mind that $r=r(\theta)$. And remember, the notation is just there to help you express your mathematical thoughts. Not the other way around.

Comment: Sorry, $\hat{r}=\hat{r}(\theta)$.